# How to fix 'Extra argument 'zoom' in call' for MapBox sceneKit (AR scene)?

Tags: swift, xcode, mapbox, scenekit, augmented-reality

The error states that it doesn't require the 'zoom' argument but all online documentation suggests otherwise.

When I've removed the 'zoom' argument it errors once again and says it needs two arguments. Am I missing another argument which I need to add instead?

Also, I've tried using the 'multiplier' argument which someone suggested using that didn't work either.

```
func createTerrain() {
    terrainNode = TerrainNode(minLat: minLat, maxLat: maxLat,
                              minLon: minLon, maxLon: maxLon)
    
    if let terrainNode = terrainNode {
        terrainNode.scale = terrainNodeScale // Scale down map
        terrainNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, -0.15, 0) // Place map slightly below clouds
        terrainNode.geometry?.materials = defaultMaterials() // Add default materials
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(terrainNode)
        
        terrainNode.fetchTerrainHeights(minWallHeight: 100.0, enableDynamicShadows: true, progress: { progress, total in
        }, completion: {
            NSLog("Terrain load complete")
        })
        
        terrainNode.fetchTerrainTexture("mapbox/satellite-v9", zoom: 14, progress: { progress, total in
        }, completion: { image in
            NSLog("Texture load complete")
            terrainNode.geometry?.materials[4].diffuse.contents = image
        })
    }
}
```

This is the part of the code that at the terrain texture and satellite image to the terrain node. I assume that I need to know the 'zoom' level but it's wanting it removed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm currently ripping my hair out. Thank you very much to anyone who comes across this post and can offer any suggestions.

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Apparently method has been changed, it doesn't have zoom argument anymore and completion closure has two arguments now - https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-scenekit/blob/5f1cab22223ec61186d8baabc37d485b32a952db/Examples/DemoStyleViewController.swift#L64

Comment: Thanks very much for the help! How would I go about adding the second completion argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fetchTextureTerrain` method seems to have been changed from your:

```
terrainNode.fetchTerrainTexture("mapbox/satellite-v9", zoom: 14, progress: { progress, total in
        }, completion: { image in
            NSLog("Texture load complete")
            terrainNode.geometry?.materials[4].diffuse.contents = image
        })
```

To something like:

```
terrainNode.fetchTerrainTexture("mapbox/satellite-v9", progress: { progress, total in
      // Some code here.

      }, completion: { image, fetchError in
            if let fetchError = fetchError {
                NSLog("Texture load failed: \(fetchError.localizedDescription)")
            }
            if image != nil {
                NSLog("Texture load complete")
                terrainNode.geometry?.materials[4].diffuse.contents = image
            }
      })
```

Notice the extra `fetchError` term in the completion block (and the removal of the `zoom` term that you noticed earlier). Unrelated but for a purely swift implementation you should use `print` statements and avoid the `NSLog`s.